# MVC 4 ModelState invalid because it is trying to auto-fill values and not accept new ones

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, modelstate, modelstatedictionary

I have a comments section.  In the view there is only a comments editor box.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { courseID = @ViewBag.courseID, userName = @User.Identity.Name }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="NewComment">
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CommentText, new { maxLength = 500})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CommentText)
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="PostComment" value="Post Comment" />
        <div id="Counter" class="CommentCounter"/>
    </div>

}
```

The model has the course the comment is linked too, date, comment text, and user.  The other values get filled in the create post method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddComment(CourseComment coursecomment, int courseID, String userName)
{
    userName = userName.Split('\\')[1];
    coursecomment.CommentDate = System.DateTime.Now;
    coursecomment.CourseID = courseID;
    coursecomment.UserName = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName).UserID;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.CourseComments.AddObject(coursecomment);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Course", new { courseID = courseID });
}
```

The problem occurs here.  The model is trying to use the `userName` parameter for the value for `courseComment.UserName` before I actually do the work and set it.  After it gets set the `ModelState` doesn't change.

Example, `domain\abc123` gets passed into the post method and also set in the `ModelState` for `UserName`.  I do some work, change the `userName` to `abc123` and find the linked ID, lets say ID = 1, to that user with said name, then plug that into the `courseComment.UserName`  `ModelState` still leaves the `domain\abc123` in there and the model stays invalid.

Now, this was working original, then I changed the underlying database around, mainly just column names and some relations.

**My solution for this.**

Move receiving the username from the post method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddComment(CourseComment coursecomment, int courseID)
{
    coursecomment.CommentDate = System.DateTime.Now;
    coursecomment.CourseID = courseID;
    coursecomment.UserName = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName).UserID; //Moved
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.CourseComments.AddObject(coursecomment);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Course", new { courseID = courseID });
}
```

to a get method.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetUserName(string userName)
{
    var ret = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName).UserID;
    return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then changed the view to be like

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserName)

....

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var userName = '@User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1]';
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetUserName", "CourseComment")',
        data: { userName: userName },
        type: 'get'
    }).done(function (data) {
        $('#UserName').val(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that all the view cares about is what's in `ModelState`. This is confusing to many devs, but it's logical when you think about it.

Essentially, `ModelState` is composed from the values of `Model`, of course, but then also from values in `ViewBag`, `ViewData`, and `Request`, which override anything set via `Model`. To understand why, imagine a scenario where the user is editing an existing object, but makes an error in one of the values, causing the form to be returned to correct their error. If the values from `Model` were use, the users edits would be completely undone, replaced with the original values on the object. However, by using the values from `Request`, `ModelState` preserves the users submitted values, allowing them to only make the necessary corrections.

Long and short, you have to be very careful about naming request parameters, `ViewBag` properties, etc., the same as properties on your model. Probably the simplest solution in your scenario is to just change the request param, `userName` to something else.

Also, for what it's worth, `ModelState` is case insensitive, so `UserName` is the same as `userName`, `username`, `USERNAME` or `UsErNaMe`.

Comment: Good for info.  I ended up doing a hidden field for it.  Then when the page was loaded value was received form javascript/ajax call.